# Help with a derivative of integral please.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm supposed to calculate the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^{2}}^{x^{8}}\sqrt{8t}dt$ the answer I got is $8x^7\cdot \sqrt{8x^8}$ but when I put this into the grading computer it is marked wrong.  I've tried solving in several different ways and always got the same answer so I used my graphing calculator to test.

I solved for $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^{2}}^{x^{8}}\sqrt{8t}dt$ with my graphing calculator's derivative and integral functions, with $x=3$.  The result was $40083336.292$.  The I tried solving with my formula, again plugging in $3$ for $x$.  The result was $4008379.039$.

Very similar, but not the same.  Is my formula wrong or is it a bug in the grading program?

Thanks for any help.  If I solved this wrongly please explain where I went wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that you apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus as in

$$\int_{x^2}^{x^8} \sqrt{8t} dt = \int_{c}^{x^8} \sqrt{8t} dt - \int_{c}^{x^2} \sqrt{8t} dt $$

then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_{x^2}^{x^8} \sqrt{8t} dt\right) = 8x^7\sqrt{8 x^8} - 2x\sqrt{8 x^2}  $$

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)=\int_{x^2}^{x^8} f(t) dt=F(t)|_{x^2}^{x^8}=F(x^8)-F(x^2)$ and so differentiating we have $g'(x)=(x^8)'f(x^8)-(x^2)'f(x^2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I guess I'm pretty stupid to miss that.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is 
$$8x^7\sqrt{8x^8}-2x\sqrt{8x^2}=4\sqrt 2\bigl(4x^{11}-x\lvert x\rvert\bigr).$$
You have to derive also w.r.t. the lower bound of integration.

Comment: Thanks, should have figured that out.